# compilador python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um assistente virtual em python, que por comando de voz é possível fazer algumas coisas. Quando o script no Pycharm ou o mesmo funciona tranquilamente, quando executar o cmd no Windows também não funciona corretamente corretamente, mas quando o script é instalado pelo pyinstaller, o programa é compilado com sucesso, mas o arquivo do exe é aberto ou o console é aberto novamente . Teria como alguem me ajudar ???

O erro é  este aqui:

(venv) C:\Users\Lina\PycharmProjects\uncapcth\build\exe.win-amd64-3.7>time.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts__startup__.py", line 40, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 37, in run
    exec(code, {'**name**': '**main**'})
  File "time.py", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\Lina\PycharmProjects\uncapcth\Assistente.py", line 3, in 
    from webbot import Browser
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\webbot__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from .webbot import Browser
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\webbot\webbot.py", line 1, in 
    from selenium import webdriver ;
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver__init__.py", line 18, in 
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 29, in 
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 27, in 
    from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 24, in 
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3__init__.py", line 7, in 
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in 
    from .packages.six.moves import queue
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 91, in **get**
    result = self._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 113, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    **import**(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'queue'

As bibliotecas usadas são: pyaudio, speech_recognition, webbot, pyautogui, pyttsx3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja converter seu script para a extensão `.exe` sem o console, você pode instalar uma biblioteca chamada `auto-py-to-exe`, que permite converter o código em um único arquivo executável e com ícone personalizado. Basta abrir o **prompt de comando** como **administrador** e digitar `pip install auto-py-to-exe` ou `pip3 install auto-py-to-exe` (caso esteja usando Python 3). Após a instalação, abra o **cmd** e digite `auto-py-to-exe`, ele vai abrir uma janela para que você possa selecionar o arquivo `.py` (seu script) para ser convertido, além da possibilidade de adicionar um ícone ao seu programa, digitar o nome, converter em um único arquivo, esconder o console (é o seu caso, é a opção "hide console"), e escolher a pasta de destino do arquivo. Assim é possível gerar o programa executável e sem o console!

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, ajudou bastante !!!, ainda tive que resolver um problema com umas das bibliotecas , mas funciono !! thanks

Comment: De nada cara, sucesso em sua carreira!